# Create an array of arrays from file reader?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to convert an excel file with multiple work sheets to json, and I found the following script to do so. However it just console logs each sheet and I want a way to have an array and each element in the array be a sheet. I have tried initializing an array and pushing `oJS` to the array every time the `forEach` runs but it doesn't work :(

```
function filePicked(oEvent) {
        // Get The File From The Input
        var oFile = oEvent.target.files[0];
        var sFilename = oFile.name;
        // Create A File Reader HTML5
        var reader = new FileReader();

        // Ready The Event For When A File Gets Selected
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            var data = e.target.result;
            var cfb = XLS.CFB.read(data, {type: 'binary'});
            var wb = XLS.parse_xlscfb(cfb);
            // Loop Over Each Sheet
            wb.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
                // Obtain The Current Row As CSV
                var sCSV = XLS.utils.make_csv(wb.Sheets[sheetName]);   
                var oJS = XLS.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(wb.Sheets[sheetName]);   

                $("#my_file_output").html(sCSV);
                console.log(oJS)
            });
        };

        // Tell JS To Start Reading The File.. You could delay this if desired
       fileOut += reader.readAsBinaryString(oFile);
       console.log(fileOut);
    }
```

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work"? Do you get an error?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get an error but lets say i have 7 sheets in the excel document. It console logs 7 arrays, one after another. I would like to simply store each array in a parent array instead of logging it each time the loop runs.

Comment: In that case, you need to define an array outside of the loop, and instead of (or in addition to) logging the output, push the new data to the array in the outer scope.

Comment: `reader.onload` runs asynchronously. You can't access the result immediately after the assignment.

Comment: @Barmar yes I guessed having first done the above suggestion before posting the question. Any alternatives?

Comment: Try using `.append()` instead of `.html()`. You're replacing the output each time instead of adding the new sheet to it.